# Dropzone plugin working inside jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog, dropzone.js

I'm trying to open the Dropzone upload control inside a jQuery dialog, it is showing the form but I can't drop any images in it.

This is the code for the dropzone control:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/dropzone.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/dropzone.js") %>\"></script>
<form action='/file-upload' class='dropzone' id='my-awesome-dropzone'></form>
```

And the code that builds the jQuery dialog:

```
dialogObj = $("#_dialogPanel").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizeable: true,
        position: { my: "center-100 bottom-40", at: "center center" },
        stack: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true
    });
```

The control is assigned to the dialog using the `.html()` property

Comment: a fiddle will be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Have you added

```
$('#my-awesome-dropzone').dropzone({  previewsContainer: "#_dialogPanel" //or whatever the css selector is for your preview area })
```

If you are doing a lot of events and callbacks, I would ignore the jQuery invocation and go for:

```
var myAwesomeDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", { previewsContainer: "#_dialogPanel"});
```

That way you can easily add events such as

```
myAwesomeDropzone.on("thumbnail", function(file,fileurl) {
    /* Add a nice green good file tick or whatever else you want to do */       
});
```

Comment: What difference would it make to add the dropzone parameters?

Comment: 1. by setting the new dropzone you ensure the dropzone is set up properly

Comment: 2. once you are sure it is working, you add the parameters to more finely control what is presented to the user (theming) and deal with events better

Comment: For example, I use it as:

Comment: `code`var myNewDropzone = new Dropzone("#newuploadedForm",  {
        url: "<?php echo ajaxulr; ?>",
        uploadMultiple: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false, 
        addRemoveLinks: false,
        clickable: true,
        previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview-template').innerHTML,
        init : function() {
            this.on("thumbnail", function(file,fileurl) { new_thumbnail_added(file); });
            this.on("totaluploadprogress", function(progress) { display_progress(progress); });
});
        }
    });

Comment: ps - are you inserting the dialog object into the form? The thumbnails are appended to the form. Sorry, I misundertood the original question...

Comment: OK - the answer to my question = the answer to your question.  Use the paramter "previewsContainer". I missed it because it's under tips and not under configuration. I will edit my reply

Comment: I finally got time to have a look at this again - I got it eventually working but not dynamically, I just got the code from the simple example in the Dropzone page. However when I add a file and it finishes uploading it navigates to that file path, any way to stop this?

Comment: When you press the upload button, you just need to prevent default